# Wordpress: error uploading images when moving to another domain

Tags: wordpress

When I move a wordpress website to another domain, I always fail in uploading images. Why is that? I can upload posts and pages but not images.

Comment: have you moved /wp-content/themes/your-theme/uploads folder to new domain?

Comment: I did. but I still couldn't upload some pictures. Some pictures I could. Maybe I uploaded too many pictures and my server didn't allow it.

Answer (score 0):

Move your `/wp-content/themes/your-theme/uploads` folder to new domain

Comment: I did. but I still couldn't upload some pictures. Some pictures I could. Maybe I uploaded too many pictures and my server didn't allow it.

Comment: how you know your server didn't allow it? any log any message?